# List values into text fields

Tags: php

I have a form with quite a few text fields.

I would like to add a functionality where I would add a textarea where user can drop multiple values, perhaps one per line, and on submit, populate those values into text fields of my form.

I use PHP and jQuery on this page. Something tells me I should go with PHP and do a loop for 
$_POST. Am I on the right track? I build the text fields via a loop anyway, on page load:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    echo '
    <div>
        <input type="text" maxlength="100" name="field[]">
    </div>';
}
```

How would I combine this with the new feature where I would separate values from a bulk submission-?

```
foreach ($_POST as $listValue) {
    echo '
    <div>
        <input type="text" maxlength="100" name="field[]" value='.$listValue.'">
    </div>';
}
```

Comment: I'm really struggling to understand how this is useful? Anyone able to enlighten me?

Comment: It makes the data entry process easier for the user, since he/she can enter multiple lines of data into a single textarea rather than tabbing through multiple text input fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll do this way.

In the form :

```
<textaera cols="20" rows="60" name="values">
```

in the PHP :

```
$array_values = explode("\n", $_POST['values']);

foreach ($array_values as $listValue) {
echo '
    <div>
       <input type="text" maxlength="100" name="field[]" value="'.htmlentities($listValue).'">
    </div>';
}
```

Comment: you forgot a `"` after `value=` but yes, this is how I would do it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Create your textarea:

```
<textarea id="field" name="field"></textarea>
```

Then parse the results in PHP:

```
$text_area_content = $_POST['field'];
$lines_array = explode("\n", $text_area_content);
```

$lines_array now contains an element for each line of the textarea.